# Access Dialog flow Context Variables in Vox implant, I have some parameters set in the dialog flow. I want to access those in Vox implant engine

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx, voximplant

My question is how can I access the parameters that are sent by dialog flow over the conversation?
For example,
When live agent hand off is done. I want to transfer to specific phone numbers which will come from dialog flow.
In short, How Can I access a parameter in Vox engine for dialog flow CX integration ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

liveAgentHandoff value is included in the response to Voximplant and your parameters will be available in the metadata field:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.ResponseMessage.LiveAgentHandoff

Here's the code sample on how to recognize a liveAgentHandoff request in Voximplant scenario

```
let number;
conversationParticipant.addEventListener(CCAI.Events.Participant.Response, (e) => {
  if (e.response.automatedAgentReply?.responseMessages) {
    e.response.automatedAgentReply.responseMessages.forEach((response) => {
      if (response.liveAgentHandoff) { 
      transfer = true; 
      number = response.liveAgentHandoff.metadata.phoneNumber;
      Logger.write('###### LiveAgentHandoff being triggered: ' +   JSON.stringify(response));
      }
    })
  }
});
```